# Apache server does not ask for authentication after a previous successful authentication

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

Here is my dilema

I have a website where I have one part of it containing some sensitive information and the other part serves as an API for a school project. Both parts are protected by basic authentication but both do not share the same password or user.

The issue I noticed with this is that when I access the site on my computer, it only allows me to view the different parts provided I have made a successful login to the part I want to visit. So it only allows for accessing the API after I have input the correct password and username and the same goes for the other part of it.
However this is not the case when I try to visit my site on my phone. My browser of choice is `opera beta`. When I visit the non API part, it asks me for a username and password which I decide not to provide, then of course it shows me an error dialog, and this is expected. Then from the page I'm on, I type in the link to get to the API part of it, but this time I supply the right password and username, and this works and gets me in, but the weird part is that if I navigate back from where I am, I can suddenly access the other part as well even though I wasn't able to previously, and I still shouldn't.

My question is, why is this happening? The usernames required for both parts are different and so are the passwords. I don't experience this if I was trying to do the same thing on my laptop using `Firefox dev edition` as my browser. Is this browser specific or is it something I can fix using the .htaccess file?

### .htaccess for non API part

```
DirectoryIndex website.html

# Disable Directory Browsing
Options -Indexes

# Displaying PHP errors
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 6143

# enable basic rewriting
RewriteEngine on

# Hide Apache version and OS identity
ServerSignature Off

# Limit request size
LimitRequestBody 102400

# Force X-XSS-Protection
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block"
</IfModule>

# Allow only required HTTP methods
<LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>

# Generate passwords using "htpasswd -bsn <username> <password>"
# copy over to the .htpasswd file
<FilesMatch "website.html$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorised access only"
    AuthUserFile /page/n/c/aaa111/configurations/.htpasswd
    Require user profile
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</FilesMatch>

# Redirect all GET requests targeted at the api towards the actual script
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteBase /aaa111
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule api/(.+)$ api/service.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

### .htaccess for API part

```
DirectoryIndex service.php

<FilesMatch ".*\.(php)$">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Authorised access only"
    AuthUserFile /page/n/c/aaa111/configurations/.htpasswd
    Require user cmpt371_app
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8
</FilesMatch>
```

I should also add that the API part is nested under the non API folder.